# Why does 'suspect' only have one s where the syllables join?

Tags: etymology, orthography

The base is the prolific "spect" and the prefix, "sus," is an assimilated form of "sub"... So I can't account for that second 's.' There's no dropping the final s in prefixing!

***[Suspect](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=suspect&allowed_in_frame=0)***:

> - early 14c., "suspected of wrongdoing, under suspicion;" mid-14c., "regarded with mistrust, liable to arouse suspicion," from Old French suspect (14c.), from Latin suspectus ....................... (see sub-) + specere "to look at" (see scope (n.1)). The notion behind the word is "look at secretly," hence, "look at distrustfully."

(Etymonline)

Comment: The word is directly from the Latin *suspectus*. I suggest you take your complaint to the Latin stack exchange.

Comment: @Murdie should pick one or t'other with a green check: It's got two good answers, and it's sayin' "put a fork in me, I'm done."  Move it from the in-box to the out-box and call it nice work.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, I don't know why you're assuming the prefix should be identified as "sus-". Why couldn't it be "su-"? In fact, Wiktionary even lists that in its entry for Latin "[sub-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sub-#Latin)". I'm not saying Wiktionary is necessarily right, but I think that option needs to be considered.

In any case, even if you're right that the prefix is "sus-", it's quite natural for a hypothetical "susspectus" to develop to "suspectus" through shortening of consonants in clusters. In fact, as far as I know (I'm not an expert), "susspectus" with /ssp/ would not even be valid as a Latin word because long consonants in Latin occured only before vowels (and maybe word-finally in some words such as *[hoc](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/2537/9)*, but we only know for sure from metrical evidence and that only tells us how these words were pronounced when followed by a vowel).

Likewise, the final consonant of "ad-" usually assimilated to a following consonant, making it long (as we see in the very word "assimilate") but we have "aspect" not "asspect".

We also see a similar thing in words prefixed with *ig-,* such as *[ignobilis](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dignobilis).* The reason for the "g" is that the stem of words such as *nobilis* used to start with "gn", so "ignobilis" really corresponds to earlier "in-gnobilis." But the spelling has "ign" not "ingn". It's thought that the "g" in "gn" represented, at least originally, a velar nasal [ŋ]. And the final consonant of the prefix "in-" assimilates in place to a following stop or nasal. So "ingn" would look like it should be pronounced [iŋŋn], which is not a valid consonant cluster in Latin. Evidently [ŋŋn] was simplified to [ŋn], which explains the spelling with "gn".

Comment: Thank you! I went back to the etymonline entry and realized I was in fact making an assumption about the prefix. I thought it identified 'sus' as the prefix, but I guess I committed illegitimate backfill. Thank you--I'm quite satisfied with the 'su' explanation and I appreciate the elaboration. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

***The prefix in 'suspect' is not 'sus', it is basically 'sub'. Again it is assimilated to following 'p' and has become 'su'.***

> " from assimilated form of sub "up to" (see sub-) + specere "to look
>   at" (see scope (n.1)). The notion behind the word is "look at
>   secretly," hence, "look at distrustfully."(http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=suspect)

***"In Latin assimilated to following -c-, -f-, -g-, -p-, and often -r- and -m-**. 
In Old French the prefix appears in the full Latin form only "in learned adoptions of old Latin compounds" [OED], and in popular use it was represented by sous-, sou-; as in French souvenir from Latin subvenire, souscrire (Old French souzescrire) from subscribere, etc.

The original meaning is now obscured in many words from Latin (suggest, suspect, subject, etc.). The prefix is active in Modern English, sometimes meaning "subordinate" (as in subcontractor); "inferior" (17c., as in subhuman); "smaller" (18c.); "a part or division of" (c. 1800, as in subcontinent).*(http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sub)